# Como configurar o log4j2.xml com parâmetros diferentes por ambiente

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

Como utilizar o log4j2 com diferentes parâmetros por ambiente no spring boot.
Preciso que o log seja gerado com um nome diferente para cada ambiente.

Answer (score 2):

Implemente o log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="teste"
    packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppenderdev" fileName="dev.log"
            filePattern="dev-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>dev - %d [%-6p] %c - %M - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppendertest" fileName="test.log"
            filePattern="test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>test - %d [%-6p] %c - %M - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender@spring.profile@" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Defina os profiles no pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile>dev</spring.profile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>hom</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>hom</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile>test</spring.profile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Não se esqueça do filtro!

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Executar usando

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true spring-boot:run -Phom
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Não entendi bem a parte da necessidade do filtro no `src/main/resources`. E a propósito, é considerado preferível usar `-DskipTests` ao se usar o `surefire`.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado por padrão o maven não faz o _property replacement_ nos _resources_, por isso o `filtering`. Veja: [resource filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). O `maven-filtering` usa este comportamento. Outra coisa: por que é considerado preferível usar `skipTests`? Na verdade o `maven.test.skip` até evita a compilação dos testes, sendo considerado pelo _surefire_, _compile_ e _failsafe_  - e qualquer outro que siga o padrão, então ele é até "preferível" para economizar um pouco de recurso ;)

Comment: só não consegui fazer com que ele não crie o arquivo dev no ambiente de testes e vice-versa, apesar de ele ficar vazio, mas pra o que eu precisava serviu e ainda vou implementar o appender de email da mesma forma, já que o cliente quer grupos diferentes de email  para receber os logs conforme o ambiente.

Comment: isso deve resolver
createOnDemand boolean The appender creates the file on-demand. The appender only creates the file when a log event passes all filters and is routed to this appender. Defaults to false.

Comment: @Otávio você não precisa ter dois appenders não, vi que tu apenas troca o nome do arquivo de log. Que tal usar a `spring.profile` em todos os lugares que está usando `dev` ou `test`?

Comment: @BrunoCésar ah sim, vc tem razão, obrigado pela dica, só no caso do email que precisarei mudar os destinatários e host do smtp também, dai acho q vou precisar usar mais. Valeu!